# Implement expand & collapse button in Android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using custom template for Android Notification in expanded state, by setting a remote view using setCustomBigContentView(remoteView). Note that I am not using DecoratedCustomViewStyle, because of which system provided expand/collapse button will not be available.

Since I am not using custom template for collapsed state, a notification in collapsed state is rendered with expand button. On clicking that button, a custom template is rendered but with no collapse button. I am trying to add that button.

I searched a lot about it but didn't get any solution. It would be really helpful if someone can provide some pointers for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution you get till now ?

Comment: I searched for more but didn't get any correct solution :(